# How do I convert my output into a list?

Tags: python, list, plot

I'm trying to plot the output of my function into a list so I can plot it as a graph. My code so far is

```
t = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

def anninos():
    for time in t:
        tfac = math.factorial(time)
        print(tfac)
anninos()
```

The output I get is

```
1
2
6
24
120
720
5040
40320
362880
3628800
```

but the output I want is

```
[1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320, 362880, 3628800]
```

What code do I need to add to get this?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) or [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to construct a list:

```
>>> import math
>>> t = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> [math.factorial(time) for time in t]
[1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320, 362880, 3628800]
>>> list(map(math.factorial, t))
[1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320, 362880, 3628800]
```

You could then return the list from your function or print it.

Comment: How about use `return [math.factorial(time) for time in t]` instead? Since that I think OP also wants to use the list later.

Comment: @Kevin: That would be more 'functional'.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Ah yes, I like this one better.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `yield` instead of `print` and do `print(list(anninos()))` instead of `anninos()`.  You could also construct a list and append to it:

```
def anninos():
    result = []
    for time in t:
        result.append(math.factorial(time))
    print(result)
```

Whenever you have a loop that just creates a list of the same things, you can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
def anninos():
    print([math.factorial(time) for time in t])
```

Answer (score 1):

You need use yield or not use funtion. You don't even use the return from a function - why do you use function?:

```
import math

t = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

def anninos(values_list):
    for time in values_list:
        yield math.factorial(time)

print list(anninos(t))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
t = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

def anninos():
    out = []
    for time in t:
        tfac = math.factorial(time)
        out.append(tfac)
    print(out)
anninos()
```